# Frida: Implementation for e expected return value compatible with void

Tags: android, frida

The following code caused the error `Implementation for e expected return value compatible with void`:

```js
Java.perform(function() {
    let Webview = Java.use("br.com.vr.beneficios.ui.activities.CreateNewPasswordActivity");
    Webview.e.overload('java.lang.Boolean').implementation = function(url) {
            console.log('Status =>', url);
            return true;
        }
});
```

I couldn't think of a way to solve it.
If anyone can help me

Comment: Next time please include the method signature (e.g. as shown in Jadx) of the method you want to hook so we can see if your hooking code is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the warning, I started studying programming a little while ago so I didn't know what else to report, so I just posted a question I had, if possible could you take a look? I think you would know how to help. @robert

Comment: Studying alone makes it a little difficult, but I'm glad it has this amazing platform.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return true :

```
Java.perform(function() {
let Webview = Java.use("br.com.vr.beneficios.ui.activities.CreateNewPasswordActivity");
Webview.e.overload('java.lang.Boolean').implementation = function(url) {
console.log('Status =>', url);
}
});
```

Comment: It worked, thank you s2, A doubt, I wanted to tell the app that such a function would always be true, but when putting the true return, it gives this error. Is there any way to do this? @johan

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept the answer to close the question. For your question I would personally use a condition, if it satisfies then it is true.

Comment: The answer is [+] WebView loadUrl => false, I wanted to turn false to true, would that be possible?, if yes, can you show me how I could be doing this?, and thanks a lot for your help s2 @johan

Comment: Another question, I'm new to frida/javascript, could you tell me where I can read to learn more about frida? @johan

Comment: ```if(url =! false){ console.log('RespSucc', url)}else{ console.log('RespErr', url) }```

Comment: In the console it came out as true, but I don't know if this response was changed in the application or is only informed in the cmd, because there is no return type "return true;" @johan

Comment: You can learn more here : https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/